# Rewrite URLs to add a slash

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to rewrite URLs to redirect to a page.

When the `/` is not at the end of `www.example.com/user/myUserName` the redirect works:

```
RewriteRule /$ /user/index.php
```

When I write `RewriteBase /` the above rule does not work, but a 404 error.

How to add a `/` at the end of `www.example.com/user/myUserName/` and still redirect to `/user/index.php`.

This can be written into the `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @johnConde I am hoping people provide an answer to my question

Comment: Me too. :)

Comment: @johnConde that would totally nullify your purpose of redirecting this question from serverfault to prowebmaster

Comment: I didn't do it. The moderators or users of ServerFault did it. They did it because this question belongs here, not at that site. And believe it or not questions get answered here, too. ;)

Comment: FWIW, the mention of `RewriteBase` with regards to the above directive is irrelevant. Since the `RewriteRule` substitution is root-relative (ie. starts with a slash), the value of `RewriteBase` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Your english seems a bit confusing...

But from what I gather, the regular expression in your pattern isn't correct.

I belive you're trying to match **everything** to `/user/index.php` so try it this way:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /user/index.php
```

Comment: That would hold good for www.MyDomainName.com/x1e, would it be good for if the domain is www.MyDomainName.com/x1e/

Comment: Absolutely, that catches **all** requests and sending them to /user/index.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're referring to a directory that doesn't exist. Is the .htaccess file in the root directory of you're server?